# Store ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets as an object to refer to later

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that will create a table of contents, listing the name of each of the worksheets currently selected by the user, together with the number of the page on which it starts when printed. I've taken the code from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841199.aspx) and adapted it a little as below.

However, when the new worksheet ("Contents") is created, that becomes the active, selected sheet, such that I can no longer use ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets to refer back to the collection of worksheets selected by the user. So I would like to store that information before creating the new sheet. How can I do this?

I have tried assigning it to a variable of type `Worksheets` as you can see, but this generates an error message. (I also tried `Collection` but to no avail.)

```
Sub CreateTableOfContents()
    ' Determine if there is already a Table of Contents
    ' Assume it is there, and if it is not, it will raise an error
    ' if the Err system variable is > 0, you know the sheet is not there
    Dim WST As Worksheet
    Dim SelSheets As Worksheets

    Set SelSheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WST = Worksheets("Contents")
    If Not Err = 0 Then
        ' The Table of contents doesn't exist. Add it
        Set WST = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("blankMagnitude"))
        WST.Name = "Contents"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Set up the table of contents page
    WST.[A2] = "Table of Contents"
    With WST.[A6]
        .CurrentRegion.Clear
        .Value = "Subject"
    End With
    WST.[B6] = "Page(s)"
    WST.Range("A1:B1").ColumnWidth = Array(36, 12)
    TOCRow = 7
    PageCount = 0

    ' Do a print preview on all sheets so Excel calcs page breaks
    ' The user must manually close the PrintPreview window
    Msg = "Excel needs to do a print preview to calculate the number of pages." & vbCrLf & "Please dismiss the print preview by clicking close."
    MsgBox Msg
    SelSheets.PrintPreview

    ' Loop through each sheet, collecting TOC information
    For Each S In SelSheets
        If S.Visible = -1 Then
            S.Select
            ThisName = ActiveSheet.Name
            HPages = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
            VPages = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
            ThisPages = HPages * VPages

            ' Enter info about this sheet on TOC
            WST.Select
            Range("A" & TOCRow).Value = ThisName
            Range("B" & TOCRow).NumberFormat = "@"
            If ThisPages = 1 Then
                Range("B" & TOCRow).Value = PageCount + 1 & " "
            Else
                Range("B" & TOCRow).Value = PageCount + 1 & " " ' & - " & PageCount + ThisPages
            End If
        PageCount = PageCount + ThisPages
        TOCRow = TOCRow + 1
        End If
    Next S
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just amended your code. Is this what you are trying? Honestly all you had to do was

Change `Dim SelSheets As Worksheets` to `Dim SelSheets` and your original code would have worked :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTableOfContents()
    Dim WST As Worksheet, S As Worksheet
    Dim SelSheets
    Dim msg As String
    Dim TOCRow As Long, PageCount As Long, ThisPages As Long
    Dim HPages As Long, VPages As Long

    Set SelSheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Contents").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set WST = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("blankMagnitude"))

    With WST
        .Name = "Contents"
        .[A2] = "Table of Contents"
        .[A6] = "Subject"
        .[B6] = "Page(s)"
        .Range("A1:B1").ColumnWidth = Array(36, 12)
    End With

    TOCRow = 7: PageCount = 0

    msg = "Excel needs to do a print preview to calculate the number of pages." & vbCrLf & "Please dismiss the print preview by clicking close."

    MsgBox msg

    SelSheets.PrintPreview

    For Each S In SelSheets
        With S
            HPages = .HPageBreaks.Count + 1
            VPages = .VPageBreaks.Count + 1
            ThisPages = HPages * VPages

            WST.Range("A" & TOCRow).Value = .Name
            WST.Range("B" & TOCRow).NumberFormat = "@"

            If ThisPages = 1 Then
                WST.Range("B" & TOCRow).Value = PageCount + 1 & " "
            Else
                WST.Range("B" & TOCRow).Value = PageCount + 1 & " " ' & - " & PageCount + ThisPages
            End If

            PageCount = PageCount + ThisPages
            TOCRow = TOCRow + 1
        End With
    Next S
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: One important thing. It's always good to use OPTION EXPLICIT :)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was after! This works great.
Out of curiosity, am I right in thinking that your change is equivalent to `Dim SelSheets as Variant`? Although I haven't yet taken the Option Explicit plunge, I had been trying to get into the habit of explicitly declaring variable types (and not using `Variant`) -- so this is making me wonder whether that is such a good idea after all!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wks as Worksheet, strName as String

For each wks in SelSheets
     strName = strName & wks.Name & ","
Next

strName = Left(strName, Len(strName) -1)

Dim arrWks() as String
arrWks = Split(strName,",")

End Sub
```

Your will have all the selected sheets, by name, in an arrWks, which you can then process through. You could also add each sheet name to a collection as well in the loop making it smoother.

It's best to stay away from ActiveSheet as much as possible. In this way you can loop through array with a counter and process

So:

```
Dim intCnt as Ingeter
For intCnt = Lbound(arrWks) to UBound(arrWks)
     Worksheets(arrWks(intCnt)).Activate
     .... rest of code .... 
Next
```

replaces

```
For Each S In SelSheets
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'd been hoping for a neater solution, but now that you've given me that it's really not so daunting I guess :) I don't know how to use collections but it sounds like it could be useful knowledge so I'll try and read up on them soon.

Comment: for your reading pleasure. you will be up on them in no time... http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/objects/Lesson6.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could store references to each sheet;

```
function getSheetsSnapshot() as Worksheet()
dim shts() As Worksheet, i As long
redim shts(ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count - 1)
for i = 0 to ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count - 1
    set shts(i) = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets(i + 1)
next
getSheetsSnapshot = shts
end function
```

fetch & store them:

```
dim oldsel() as Worksheet: oldsel = getSheetsSnapshot()
```

do your stuff then refer back to the original selected sheets;

```
for i = 0 to ubound(oldsel)
    msgbox oldsel(i).name
next
```